# How to select single XML node value fastest

Tags: xml, linq, datareader

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<test>
    <exam paper="math" section="third" value="dull">
        <place>college</place> 
    </exam> 
</test>
```

and i want to get the value of "section" and place "tag" with best performance. Shall i use linq or xmldatareader? please share the code also

Comment: xml - <?xml version='1.0'?>
       <test> <exam paper="math" section="third" value="dull"> <place>college</place>  </test>

Comment: Your XML is invalid. `exam` element is not closed.

Comment: <?xml version='1.0'?> <test> <exam paper="math" section="third" value="dull"> <place>college</place></exam> </test>
now with the corrected xml

Comment: @user1607035: You can edit your answer rather than adding comments.

Comment: Why is performance a concern for you here? Are you experiencing slow behavior using your current implementation? Or is this an example of premature optimization? Instead of asking for "best performance," perhaps you could provide information about how fast would be "fast enough" for you?

Comment: thanks Stripling Warrior - currently the system uses FreeThreadedDOMDocument30 to parse the xml document (as the code was migrated from vb) I wanted to use dot.net classes and get the best performance from the code, hence the request

Comment: @user1607035: But why do you need "the best performance?" Is this part of your code consumed hundreds of times per second? Or are you just assuming that faster code is better? Wouldn't it be best to have code that's easy to understand and maintain, as long as it's fast enough for your purposes?

Comment: i under your question @StriplingWarrior ...instead of using the word best performance i should have used 'better then vb code'...my apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XmlDataReader would probably be faster than LINQ to XML, but LINQ to XML will probably be easier to write and maintain.

I was able to run the following code ten thousand (10,000) times in just over 0.1 seconds: do you need better performance than that?

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(
@"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<test>
    <exam paper=""math"" section=""third"" value=""dull"">
        <place>college</place>
    </exam>
</test>");
var info = 
    (from test in doc.Elements("test")
    from exam in test.Elements("exam")
    select new{
        section = exam.Attribute("section").Value,
        place = exam.Element("place").Value
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: thats great StriplingWarrior, i am getting the following error when I call this on button submit event, i have already added the namespace system.xml.linq.The error is highlighted on the following code - doc.Elements("test")
Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'.  'SelectMany' not found.  Are you missing a reference or a using directive for 'System.Linq'?

Comment: @user1607035: Well... are you missing a using directive for 'System.Linq'?

Comment: thanks Striplingwarrior, actually i have referenced it already so cant really figure out the problem..but i used XMLNode to reference through nodes basically using the following commands -
                sec= node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("section").InnerText;
                place= node.FirstChild.InnerText;